# check if username exists and generate new username if it does PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation, function

I am trying to write a simple function that checks if a username exists in the db and if so to call another function to generate a new username. My code seems to fall over though:

Username Function:-

```
$user1=create_username($fname, $company);

function create_username($surname, $company){

//$name_method=str_replace(" ", "", $surname);
$name_method=$surname.$forename;
$company_name_method=str_replace(" ", "", $company);


if(strlen($name_method)<=5)
{
    $addition=rand(11,99);
    $first=$addition.$name_method;
}
else
{
    $first=substr($name_method,0,5);
}
if(strlen($company_name_method)<=5)
{
    $addition2=rand(11,99);
    $second=$addition2.$company_name_method;
}
else
{
    $second=substr($company_name_method,0,5);
}
$middle=rand(100,1000);

$username=$first.$middle.$second;
return($username);
}
```

Check Username Function:

```
check_user($user1, $dbc, $fname, $company);

function check_user($user1, $dbc, $surname, $company){
$check_username="SELECT username FROM is_user_db WHERE username='$user1'";
$resultx=mysqli_query($dbc, $check_username) or die("Could not check username");
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($resultx);
if($num_rows>0)
{
    $user1=create_username($fname, $company);
    check_user($user1, $dbc, $fname, $company);

}
else
{
    return($user1);
}
}
```

It just seems to return the original username.

Comment: You appear to be passing only 1 name to your function.

Comment: Your first line of code seems to be passing first name, your function expects surname... but then references forename. You need to go through line by line and decide what you want your code to do. It'll help you (and us) if you format the code with some indentation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to re-factor your code a little. Write out the steps on paper; that helps me. So far, I can see:

1. You want to check a username is unique on form submission
2. If it's not, generate a new username

So, check the username when your form is POSTed:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (username_unique($_POST['username'])) {
            // carry on processing form
        }
        else {
            $suggested_username = suggest_username($_POST['username']);
            // display form, with new suggested username?
        }
    }
```

And then write your functions:

```
<?php
    // following on from code from above

    function check_username($username) {
        // get database connection (I use PDO)
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users_tbl WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($username));
        $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
        return ($row->count > 0); // if 'count' is more than 0, username already exists
    }

    function suggest_username($username) {
        // take username, and add some random letters and numbers on the end
        return $username . uniqid();
    }
```

Hopefully this will help. Obviously it'll need some modification to work in your set-up, but this is the general flow you'll need.

Comment: Great - this is not exactly what I was after but the essence and process is there. Thanks for your input :)